# Swift 2 JSON Parsing but not append global value array

Tags: json, swift2

my problem is:

```
class BackVC: UITableViewController {

  var strArr = Array<String>()
```

this value initializing with viewDidLoad() function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  strArr = Array<String>()
```

and write this Json parsing codes behind

```
   let generalUrl = NSURL(string: "my json address")
    let path = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(generalUrl!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      if let dataPath = data {
        do {
          let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataPath, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

          if let catArr = jsonResult["categories"] as? NSArray {
            for c in catArr {
              self.strArr?.append(c as! String)
            }
          }
        } catch {
          print("json data read error")
        }
      }
    }
    path.resume()
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell

    print("strArr") or print("\(strArr)") is nil
  }
```

what's wrong?

Comment: This code cannot compile because of the question mark in this line `self.strArr?.append(c as! String)` since `strArr` is declared as non optional.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer to define `arrays` in swift like this `[String]`.

```
// define array
var strArr = [String]()

// add item to array
for c in catArr {
   self.strArr.append(c as! String)
}

// get item
let text = self.strArray[indexPath.row]
print("next:\(text)")
```

Comment: `[String]()` and `Array<String>()` are absolutely equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous answer...

Prefer to initialize arrays in swift like this

```
var strArr = [String]()
```

or the long hand more explicit version

```
 `var strArr: Array<String> = [String]()`
```

alternativley to the above loop

```
  // add item to array
 for i in 0...catArr.count-1 {
 self.strArr[i].append(c as! String)
 }
```